# Simple explanation on 'How vacuum is treated in the different quantum gravity theories?' And is there a theory where there is NO space without matter?

Tags: spacetime, vacuum, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

Could you please make an easy-to-understand synopsis on how the different quantum gravity theories (loop quantum gravity, causal dynamic triangulation, and the many other) treat empty space? That could be used to explain it to my grandma (who is not a physicist)?

I'm especially looking for a theory which assumes that there is *no* (!!) space without 'loading' with energy density (curvature). Is there such a theory?
String theory is *not* background independent, it still assumes a space being the screen on which everything plays. Could the Wheeler-DeWitt equation be such a thing as it is the Schroedinger equation of quantum gravity?

Comment: I'd suggest reframing the first paragraph of your question (or possibly removing it entirely and including parts of it in your second paragraph). Until one reaches the second paragraph, it looks like you're asking people to write a Wiki page of sorts, which is not encouraged. Relatedly, also consider rephrasing your title.

Comment: Don't you think this is kind of insulting to grandmothers (many of whom are highly intelligent and educated)? Or maybe just your own grandmother? The title and the body of the text disagree which you mean.

Comment: Sorry for that. Tried to improve.